# Feasible digital bit rate in SSB

Tags: bit-rate

Decades ago, I worked on a suppressed-carrier SSB transceiver with a carrier frequency of 8.8 KHz.  The bandwidth was sufficient for speech communication, comprehensible but not high-quality.

For a general idea of the original application: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulated_ultrasound
but we used 8.8KHz because ultrasound doesn't have sufficient range.

I'm wondering how to estimate the bit rate achievable if the mikes and speakers were converted to be FSK modems.  Considering a digital application rather than analog audio.

After checking the link in tobalt's comment, it seems that I have to know the noise level, but that will vary depending on the location and the distance between the devices.  The idea is remote control of an unmanned submarine without cables.  The controller's analog steering and speed controls should be not have jumps, so an excess-three code might be sufficient to reject and retry errors.  The reason for converting to digital instead of having frequencies proportional to the analog values is to avoid interference with other devices by sending packets for each change in control values.  But then the packets would require addressing which excess-three would not help with.  However, the chances of an erroneous address matching another nearby device would be small.

Since voice was comprehensible in the equipment I worked on forty years ago, I assume bandwidth is more than sufficient for control signals.  But the real issue is whether it is sufficient for data returned to be of any value.

Comment: 1st: For sure the carrier frequency was not 8.8kHz, 2nd: FSK is not SSB, 3rd: There are other proved modulation techniques for data transmission, so we are not going to reinvent the warm water.

Comment: It was for voice communications, and the frequency was higher than I can sing but low enough to hear.  Instead of an antenna, it had an underwater transducer.  It _was_ SSB, not FSK.  I asked about feeding FSK _into_ it instead of voice.  It was also the size of a filing cabinet with one of the tubes being bigger than my fist.

Comment: the modulation scheme does not matter for purely digital communication. It is only about SNR. Read about Shannons noisy channel theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem

Comment: Short answer: enough for control (out to some distance, beyond which attenuation drags you down below the noise floor... sorry, power and noise level *are* essential ingredients here), and almost definitely not enough for much of a data return, unless you're talking about sampling a really small number of scalar quantities (like temperature and pressure).

Comment: (also, how do you make it bidirectional? FDM? TDM?)

Comment: Like I said, packets rather than continuous, the same way TCP is bidirectional.  The distance wouldn’t be great, but I can assure you (after more than ten years as a sonarman) that sound travels for miles.  The question was about bit rate, which data return would be the major part of.

Comment: There is an article about this on linux.com: The Internet of Underwater Things: Open Source JANUS Standard for Undersea Communications https://www.linux.com/topic/embedded-iot/internet-underwater-things-open-source-janus-standard-undersea-communications/

Comment: @DDuck so, that's pretty interesting, as it represents a worked-out system. The JANUS "Initial Band" in the spec sends 160 raw bits per second, with rate-1/2 FEC, so that's 80bps of payload minus the overhead for headers and preamble and such.